# Using a for loop to output to a text file

Tags: python-3.x

What I aim to achieve with the code below is that 
Any number of students can be entered
The for loop must then loop over this number until ID numbers are filled in for each student.
e.g if students = 6 
the for loop must run 6 times

it must then write these ID numbers to an external text file.

```
 idStore = open('RegForm.txt', 'w')
 students = int(input("Enter how many students are registering: "))

for student in students:
    ID = int(input("Enter Thier ID Numbers: "))
    print(student)

idStore.write(ID +"\n")

idStore.close()
```

Comment: What happens if you move `idStore.write(ID +"\n")` inside the loop? Also, you should use `for _ in range(len(students))` (although not very pythonic). `int` is not iterable so your current loop will raise an exception

Comment: Requiring the user to input things in an interactive loop is not a particularly helpful design. What happens if they lose track in a long list of students or make a typo? Could you change the program to read numbers from a file and let the user edit the file until they are satisfied? Then they don't have to keep track of how many entries are in the file, either; just stop when you reach EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `students` variable is an `int` as you have declared it yourself and you can't iterate over `int`.

Instead try iteration over a `range()` inside [Context Manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/):

```
with open('RegForm.txt', 'w') as idStore:
    students = int(input("Enter how many students are registering: "))
    for _ in range(students):
        ID = input("Enter Thier ID Numbers: ")
        print(ID)
        idStore.write(ID +"\n")
```

Also, avoid converting your `ID` to `int` as you are will encounter:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```